# how to get aws lambda to run project at set intervals

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, jar

I have a few jar files that are executed with arguments on an Ubuntu server running on a crontab.

problem is I need a better uptime. how can I duplicate my setup from working on a VM to AWS lambda.
and would lambda be the go to here, because It'll be much easier using EC2 Right?

Comment: the problem is more running my project. My code needs to run with arguments to work. in ubuntu it was simple..just set up a bash script, but i cant get it running in lambda at all. once its running I'll look to run it chronologically.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would create CloudWatch (CW) Rule [schedule expressions for Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) that triggers a lambda function. **cron expressions** are supported, which would enable you to easily port your current `cron` expressions from the instance, to CW.

In that case, your rule would trigger a lambda function.

Comment: Minor comment: This functionality moved to the EventBridge service. It is functionally the same, but for future reference I'd like to point to the new documentation in the EventBridge service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html